# How to create a banner for android app which can fits all different kinds of screen?

Tags: android, banner, density-independent-pixel

I'm going to create a banner at the top of screen. But I don't know how to fits all different kinds of screen.

Comment: And I don't think that question is what I want. I don't want to use admob at first. I'll use my own banner. But I want it to show on all devices full width, but maybe the fix height.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you want to use the different resolution folders provided in the Android application structure. You would need to create a banner for each type: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and then Android would determine which one to use based on the resolution of the device 
that is using your application. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I can't use different layout. Because my banner is from server. It's a html file.